# How to convert HTML page with image and all styles to PDF then download it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to convert my web page as it is in PDF with multiple pages

Used jsPDF

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');

doc.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    doc.save('html.pdf');
});
</script>
```

jsPDF converting as it is page in pdf but without image and it shows only one A4 size page. i want whole webpage in PDF with multiple A4 size pages.

Comment: where is you image?

Comment: For single page you can right click and select print, then save it as pdf. However it will not work for multiple pages

Comment: @priyanshisrivastava image is on localhosts image folder

Comment: okay, so you are loading your images in your html page then creating pdf?

Comment: @aMJay wants to create pdf onclick of button with the current content on page . and on right click, pdf removes all the styles

Comment: @priyanshisrivastava yes, created page with html, css, & bootstrap and wants as it is on pdf

Answer (score 1):

Well, jsPDF DOES support converting HTML page with image to pdf. However, `addHtml()` is [deprecated](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases/tag/v2.0.0). You should consider to use it's new [vector-supporting API](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases/tag/v2.0.0), `html()`. This [blog](https://medium.com/@weihui.guo/save-html-page-and-online-images-as-a-pdf-attachment-with-one-click-from-client-side-21d65656e764) might be helpful as well. You'll need to use a newer version of html2canvas though. I am using `html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.11`.

```
function GeneratePDF() {
  let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.html(document.body, {
    callback: function (pdf) {
        // pdf.save('test.pdf');
        window.open(output('bloburl'));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: yeah, missing ) here: window.open(output('bloburl')); updated.

Answer (score 0):

jsPdf does not support adding image the way you are trying to add it, because addtHtml function uses html2canvas module, to convert your html to canvas, so jsPdf can render it into pdf. According to one gihtub issue, there is problem when using images with html2canvas, [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/722) is the link to that issue, use that to modify addHtml function, or try using jsPdf the way it is meant to be used and add image like [this](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-addImage.html).

Comment: it will be a solution ..but html2canvas just taking an screenshot for creating pdf. and also we cant take more than one page also,